# How to create regex with multiple variables in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a regex in python which includes string variables to find the presence of those strings in the input sentence.

For  example:

Input sentences:

`In 2009, I was in Kerala. I love that place.`

String 1 = **I**, String 2 = **was**

This should return me the sentence which contains **I** and **was** in that order. ie, **In 2009, I was in Kerala** should be returned. **String1** and **String2** can be anywhere in the sentence but **String2** should come only after **String1**.

This is what I did so far:

```
r'([ A-Za-z0-9]*)'+string1+'([^\.!?]*)'+string2+'([^\.!?]*[\.!?])'
```

The problem is it detects **I** in **in** also. I don't want that. I want exactly **String1** and **String2**.

Can anyone throw some idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Try putting `\b`s around the strings. E.g. `r'...\b'+string1+r'\b...\b'+string2+r'\b...'`

Comment: `\b` means "word boundary."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my suggestion in the comment above, just adding `\b`s around the strings. I've left the rest of your regular expression as-is:

```
r'([ A-Za-z0-9]*)\b{string1}\b([^\.!?]*)\b{string2}\b([^\.!?]*[\.!?])'.format(
    string1=string1, string2=string2)
```